# Query .json to url with given number of objects

Tags: json, rest, servlets

I am getting data in an array in .json format, but there is a very large amount of it and the response time is very long. Is there a tag I can add to the url, such as **data==4**, to get only 4 objects inside a 'products' array?

This is the url:

https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?action=process&tagtype_0=categories&tag_contains_0=contains&tag_0=breakfast_cereals&tagtype_1=nutrition_grades&tag_contains_1=contains&tag_1=A&additives=without&ingredients_from_palm_oil=without&json=1

Comment: How is this related to composer?

Comment: You forgot to share the code you are using

Comment: Hello, Nico Hasse. I don't understand what code you need to see to answer the question... The question is very specific. The query returns a lot of results and I only want to get 4. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Any code would be fine. If you want the API to be filtered, why not ask the maintainers of that API?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only code I can add is the filter itself in the URL request. I already made the query to the api maintainers, but I have not received an answer.